# Renaming properties from custom react-query hook

Tags: reactjs, rename, react-query

I made a custom hook with React Query. And I want to rename a value called "data" from React Query to "customUser", so if I have multiple hooks in 1 file I don't have to worry about multiple variables called "data".

[image: Custom Hook]

But when I rename the data value to customUser, It won't work.

[image]

I don't want all these values, I only want the data value returned and named as customUser
[image]

Comment: The problem isn't with the renaming it is with the Axios request, [Look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69995724/use-react-query-with-typescript/70001155#70001155)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

react-query will always put exactly in the cache what you return from the `queryFn`. Since you are using `axios`, what you are returning is an object with multiple fields, like `headers`, `status`, `statusText` and `data`. It's the type [AxiosResponse](https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/7d6bddba2d8de29c263feaef4c40daa50cb4b176/index.d.ts#L83-L90), and you are putting all of it in the react-query cache.

Then, react-query will give you all of this in the `data` field of the result returned from `useQuery`. That means that `useCustomUser().data` is actually the `AxiosResponse`, where your "real data" is also in `.data`.

So if you rename:

```
const { data: customUser } = useCustomUser()
```

`customUser.data` will have the data you are looking for.

Confusing? Yes, very much so. Which is why many people opt to *not* store too much in their cache when working with axios by doing something like:

```
export const fetchUser = () => axios.get(url).then(response => response.data)
```

only caching the `data` part of the AxiosResponse, and discarding things like `statusText`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I figured it out by myself but I think this will help other people :)

Answer (score 0):

When accessing the data response that you want to use inside data (before renaming) you access it by using “data.data”. After renaming you simply use “customUser.data”.

Comment: Yes I know, But that won't work without @ts-ignore, because I have an interface called ICustomUser with all the data from the response. See here https://prnt.sc/1ztj7mw

* Edit: Well after thinking about that twice, It will not work without the renaming to customUser, I will come back to this 