# Use react-query with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, interface, react-query

I am trying to use react-query with TypeScript and providing the result of a request with a ts interface. Now I have the following problem

[image]

The value from "data" is this
[image]

But I can't access it, because I specified the result in an interface
[image]

- Edit: I forgot to add the hook and interface.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Could you pls show how your function ```useCustomUser``` looks like?

Comment: What is ICustomUser?

Comment: I've added extra screenshots @KlimovPeter :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I fixed it. Added this to the `fetchUser` function, Now it will return only the data and not the whole request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you correctly type the `fetchUser` function, we could make this typesafe.

First we have the fetcher function. Here we specify the return type of the data. In this case `ICustomUser` and destructure it from an `http` lib like `axios`.

```
export async function fetchUser(id: string) {
  const { data } = await http.get<ICustomUser>(`devices/${id}`);

  return data;
}
```

Then when you return your `useCustomUser` hook, the returned data will be of type `ICustomUser`.

```
// data will be of type ICustomUser
const { data } = useCustomHook();
```

Plus it might not be necessary to type the `useCustomHook` function. Typescript will implicitly type this for you. You might check this when you hover over the function in VS Code.